# Steps to calculate the MGF of (1+sum of gamma distribution) over gamma distributions

Tags: gamma-distribution, moment-generating-function

What is the best way or steps to calculate the moment generating function (mgf) of (1+sum of gamma distribution) over gamma distributions? Is it the same way to derive beta distributions?

I am trying to find the mgf of $$\exp[-(1+\sum X_j)/Y]$$

where $X$ are gamma distributions that have the same scale factor, say $m,$ and $Y$ also is a gamma distribution with scale factor $n.$

What I did is split it into $$\exp[-1/Y]\exp[\sum X_j /Y].$$

I managed to find the mgf of $\exp[-1/Y]$ which is $\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(m\right)}\left(ms\right)^{m/2}K\left(2\sqrt{ms}\right)$, but I am not sure what steps to do to find the mgf of the sum of $X$ over $Y$ ratio.

Comment: The answer depends on what you are actually summing.  For instance, obtaining an answer is easy and instantaneous if all the Gamma distributions have the same scale factor, but harder otherwise.  Could you post information about the specific sum you're working on?

Comment: Hi, I have a problem in my research like this, whereby i am trying to solve the mgf of the Exp[-(1+sum(X))/Y], where X is the gamma distributions that have the same scale factor, say m, and Y is also gamma distribution with scale n. What i did is split it into Exp[-1/Y]Exp[sum(X)/Y]. I manage to find the mgf of Exp[-1/Y] which is $\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(m\right)}\left(ms\right)^{m/2}K\left(2\sqrt{ms}\right)$, but I am not sure what steps to do to find the mgf of the sum of X over Y ratio.. please do guide @whuber

Comment: Thank you for the explanation: could you please edit your question to include that information?  (Not everybody reads through all the comments.) Note, too, that your equations become more readable when you mark them up in $\TeX$, which I see you know: just delimit them with dollar signs \$.

Comment: Your approach will not work because $\exp(-1/Y)$ and $\exp(\sum X_j/Y)$ are not independent.

Comment: thanks @whuber, so then, now i do know that the mgf of  \sum[X] is \prod[(1/(1+s/m))^m], then, the constant \(1+sum(X)) is equal to \exp[-s]*prod[(1/(1+s/m))^m] .. is this correct... Can I know just multiply the mgf above with the inverse mgf of Y ...